# How can I create a score overlay for replays?

Tags: starcraft-2

Husky and Day[9] use similar score overlays (see image) in their shows. How does this work? Can I use any image I want for this? How are the names inserted and how do the scores get updated (e.g. 1:1)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These overlays are third party applications that the casters add to the display screen before they are shown to the public.

The names and scores are typed into this application and it is shown on the second/display screen. They do the updating off camera/screen. It's usually why you see it some other screen before the in game screen is shown with the names and scores already updated.

According to [this thread](http://www.teamliquid.net/blogs/viewblog.php?topic_id=127839), Day[9] used to/is using [InfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/)

[CraftBoard](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=320774) is an newer application for you to use to do the same thing.

Comment: So Day[9] creates images for every score possible?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that thread is outdated and he's using something different like Craftboard or other type of program. Essentially the majority of the overlay is the same and the only parts that change (as you can see in the Craftboard thread) is that the user types in the names of the players and the score.